# Magento 1.9.0.1 doesn't show product items in magento order view page

Tags: magento

[image]

When i place an order there is no details show in admin order view page. No item shows related to products item "Item order" grid. I am using magento 1.9.0.1.

I have replaced all fresh magento files on server. there is no error in error log

Please any one can help.

Comment: have you overriden the file from where the items are displayed here?

Comment: Yes i have replaced fresh magento file of 1.9.0.1 after not displaying but not getting any sucess

Comment: please remove or comment the overiden file, so that the items will be displayed frm the base file

Comment: Sorry for confusion but i am not override any core file of magento for admin panel. but we have a module of one check out and on that page all product item are shows

Comment: please enable the template path hints to find the location of that file and then you can identify the reason urself

Comment: from Where i can enable the template path hint for magento admin panel order view page ? I have problem in magento admin panel order view page . please check my screenshot. product item doesn't show in magento order view page.